# Jquery object prototyping scope this on custom object

Tags: jquery, object, scope, prototype

I think I am getting confused with the scope of this.  Here is my code:

```
Object.defineProperty(jQuery.fn, "Horiz", {//Gets or sets the element's ControlType to: "Grid" 
    get: function () {
        Debug.WriteLine("Get");
        Debug.WriteLine($(this).attr("class"));
    },
    set: function () {
        return $(this).attr("data-ControlType","Grid")
    }
}).bind(this);
```

When I call it from the function it is declared in I get `undefined`.  However if I search for it through jquery in another function using `$(.UI.SearchBox).Horiz;`  the `horiz` function properly has the object defined to `this`.

```
function pagePop() {
    Debug.WriteLine("PagePop init...");
    var pageHeader = Header("PageTitle", "Receiving Report >");//Creates the page header
    var subHeader = Header("PageSubTitle","Container Search")
    Debug.WriteLine("Header:  "+$(pageHeader).html());
    $("#pageCanvas").append(pageHeader);
    $("#pageCanvas").append(subHeader);

    var PageGrid = new System.UI.Control.Grid();
    $(PageGrid.Node).appendTo("#pageCanvas");
    PageGrid.Width = 1280;

    var searchBoxRow = new System.UI.Control.RowDefinition();
    searchBoxRow.Width = 1280;
    searchBoxRow.Height=100;
    $(searchBoxRow.Node).appendTo(PageGrid.Node);

    var deatilsGridRow = new System.UI.Control.RowDefinition();
    deatilsGridRow.Width = 1280;
    deatilsGridRow.Height = 560;
    $(PageGrid.Node).append(deatilsGridRow.Node);

    var ContainerSearchBox = new SearchBox();
    $(searchBoxRow.Node).append(ContainerSearchBox.Node);
    ContainerSearchBox.Width = 1080;
    ContainerSearchBox.Height = 40;
    ContainerSearchBox.PlaceholderText = "Container Number";
    $(ContainerSearchBox).Horiz;//Calls the horiz function through object properties

    test();
}

function test() {
    Debug.WriteLine("Test init");
    $(".UI_SearchBox").Horiz;
}
```

Why is it when I call `$(ContainerSearchBox).Horiz` from the `pagePop()` function I get undefined for `this` in the `horiz` function.  Yet when I call it from the `test()` function the `horiz` function can see the object correctly as `this`.  Can someone please explain this to me?  Also how do I fix the code to get it to do what I want?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit:  Here is code for containerSearchBox:

```
System.UI.Control = {};    
SearchBox: function () {//Creates a default styled searchbox
        this.Node;
        //Creates the wrapper for the textbox and the button
        this.nodeCreate=function(){
            var wrapper = $("<div/>", {
                class: "UI_SearchBox"
            });
            var inputField = $("<input/>", {
                type: "text",
                class: "UI_SearchBox_Input"
            });
            $(inputField).appendTo(wrapper);
            var searchBtn = $("<div/>", {
                class: "UI_SearchBox_Button"
            });
            //Adds Mouse event behaviors
            $(searchBtn).mousedown(function () {
                $(this).css("background-image","url("+System.UI.Graphics.Icon("Search","PNG","Light")+")")
                $(this).css("background-color", SystemTheme);
            })
            $(searchBtn).mouseup(function () {
                $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + System.UI.Graphics.Icon("Search", "PNG", "Dark") + ")");
                $(this).css("background-color", "white");
            })
            $(searchBtn).mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + System.UI.Graphics.Icon("Search", "PNG", "Dark") + ")")
                $(this).css("background-color", "white");
            })
            $(searchBtn).appendTo(wrapper);
            this.Node=wrapper;
        }
        this.nodeCreate();
    }
```

Comment: `$(ContainerSearchBox)` doesn't refer to a DOM element, it's just a jQuery wrapper around some JS object. So in `Horiz`, `$(this).attr()` doesn't exist because that only works with DOM elements.

Comment: But if I just do console.log(this) i get undefined.  Why is that?

Comment: Also how would I change the object from the horiz function? since i cant use $(this).attr

Comment: What object are you trying to change? What's in `ContainerSearchBox`?

Comment: ContainerSearchBox is a div create in memory then applied to page.  I want to change the ContainerSearchBox that has already been applied to the page.  For example:

Comment: i added code for ContainerSearchBox.  Basically just an object.